# Error - AngularJS Uncaught TypeError:angular.service is not a function at taskService.js:2

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-module

I'm having these errors in angularJS, with well-imported libraries, I don't know what might be happening. Exactly these two:

> Uncaught TypeError: angular.service is not a function
>           at taskService.js:2
>
> taskFactory.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: angular.factory is not a function
>           at taskFactory.js:2

**taskService:**

```
    angular.module("myApp")
    angular.service("taskService", ["$localStorage", function ($localStorage) { 
        this.getTasks = function () {
            return $localStorage.tasks;
        } //let's go
    }]);
```

**taskFactory.js:**

```
    angular.module("myApp")
    angular.factory("taskFactory", ["$localStorage", function ($localStorage) { 
        var putTasks = function (tasks) {
            $localStorage.tasks = tasks;
        }
        return putTasks=putTasks; //the opposite of this

    }]);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and please use the English language to ask questions..

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing `angular.factory` you have to call/create  factory or service on module creation object. So you can do as below :

```
angular.module("myApp").service("taskService", ["$localStorage", function ($localStorage) { 
    this.getTasks = function () {
        return $localStorage.tasks;
    } //let's go
}]);
```

OR

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp");
myApp.service("taskService", ["$localStorage", function ($localStorage) { 
    this.getTasks = function () {
        return $localStorage.tasks;
    } //let's go
}]);
```

Services are registered to modules via the Module API.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services for reference.